# nvarchar & varchar with Oracle & SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2005, jdbc

I need to upload some data from an Oracle table  to a SQL Server table. The data will be uploaded to the SQL server using a Java processing utilising JDBC facilities.

Is there any benefit in creating the SQL server columns using nvarchar instead of varchar?

Google suggests that nvarchar is used when UNICODE characters are involved but i am wondering does nvarchar provide any benefit in this situation? (i.e. when the source data of the SQL Server table comes from an Oracle database running a Unix environment?)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have found out, nvarchar stores unicode characters - the same as nvarchar2 within Oracle. It comes down to whether your source data is unicode - or whether you anticipate having to store unicode values in future (e.g. internationalized software)

Comment: No i am only uploading ascii characters. Thanks